# issue with read in file and set it to variables

Tags: java

Good morning!
Ok so I got a problem with my code, i'm trying to read in a file with arrays. But, the thing is that, whenever I try to set it to a variable method, I get a NullPointerException error. I'm trying to get read in a file that contains info about student's full name, gpa and attendance. Here's an example of the text file `Week#   Y   Last    First   ID  Major   GPA`
Im supposed to count the weeks and the Y means if the student was present or absent. 
Anyway

I found another way to read in the file and set the variables but then I when the while loop runs it only runs for a certian amount of text and not the whole file, here is an example of it:

```
input.nextLine();
String weekNum = input.next();
System.out.print(""+weekNum);//I have this code in a while loop
```

here is my other code (complete) that i've been trying to figure out for hours, can someone please help?

```
        Scanner filechecker = new Scanner("C:/.txt");
        java.io.File file = new java.io.File("C:/.txt");


        Scanner input = new Scanner (file);

        funy [] student = new funy [6] ;


        for (int i=0; i<6; i++){

            input.nextLine();
            String weekNum = input.next();
            student[i].sessionList.add(weekNum);
            System.out.print(""+weekNum);
            String atten = input.next();
            student[i].absentSessionList.add(atten);
            System.out.print("\t "+atten);
            lastName = input.next();
            student[i].setLastName(lastName);
            System.out.print("\t"+lastName);
            firstName = input.next();
            student[i].setFirstName(lastName);
            System.out.print("     "+firstName);
            ID = input.next();
            student[i].setID(ID);
            System.out.print("\t"+ID);
            major = input.next();
            student[i].setMajor(major);
            System.out.print("\t"+major);
            GPA = input.nextDouble();
            student[i].setGPA(GPA);
            System.out.print("\t"+GPA+" ");
            System.out.println("\t");
            input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            student[i].addAttendanceIndicator(weekNum, atten);
        }


        System.out.println(student[0]);//you can ignore these



        System.out.printf("Abs Rate: %.3f\n", student[0].getAbsenteeRate());//this too

    }

}
`
```

Comment: Can you please post exception line

Comment: You're only reading six lines, is that normal ? BTW, could you please reduce your example into a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ?

Comment: this is line student[i].sessionList.add(weekNum);   its  the first line in the for loop.

Answer (score 1):

You defined

```
funy [] student = new funy [6] ;
```

But this array contains only null objects so you are getting NullPointerException at:

```
student[i].sessionList.add(weekNum);
```

as you state in the comments because student[i] are null for all i values.

You need to create a new funy object:

```
funy yourNewFuny = new funy(...);
```

And then at the end of the loop:

```
student[i] = yourNewFuny;
```

It would be something like:

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++){  // take care with the index like other answer states
    input.nextLine();
    String weekNum = input.next();
    String atten = input.next();
    // read the rest of the info

    funy aFuny = new funy(weekNum, etc); // I don't know how you create funy objects
    student[i] = aFuny;
}
```

## **OP EDIT:**

```
while(input.hasNextLine()){//while loop added

            input.nextLine();
            weekNum = input.next();
            //reads in the variables

        funy yourNewFuny = new funy();//last line on while loop

        for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        student[i] = yourNewFuny;
        student[i].sessionList.add(weekNum);
```

it works but it seems to only get one student's info. But thank you so much for your help!!! You really helped me a lot

Comment: it's not this. This is to skip the empty lines and the for loop doesn't even run a loop.

Comment: Thank you, but where should I add the new funy object?

Comment: Store the information that the constructor needs in variables inside the loop. When you have them all create the funy object and then asign it to the array.

Comment: I created a while loop to set the variables and then I created the for loop and added the new yourNewFuny on top of the for loop and the student [i]= yourNewFuny inside the for loop at the end. But I still got the same error, I don't know what I'm doing wrong, I feel so stupid right now

Comment: Edit my answer with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You are using

```
for (int i=0; i<6; i++)
```

so it only runs the code in your loop 6 times. Try using

```
while(input.hasNextLine()) {...
```

instead